# NUnit- Object dispose

Tags: nunit

I have a test application, that contains 29 Test's inside Single TestFixture.I have defined single TestFixtureSetUp and TestTearDown.Each test internally create many Objects which inturn contains many Thread. Till Now I didnt used IDisposable.

My Doubt: Will the objects be disposed after completing each test by the Nuint. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Sorry, if i am wrong.
Thanks,
Vigi

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the objects will be processed by the garbage collector non-deterministically. Nothing special is done by NUnit to dispose of anything created in the test, I've often had situations where I've crashed the test runner. You'll probably want to manage and destroy the threads inside each test.

Comment: Thanks..:)                                                           I will update the test with proper manage of thread.